# Overriding Object.equals VS Overloading it

Tags: java

Reading: Effective Java - Second Edition by Joshua Bloch

**Item 8 - Obey the general contract when overriding equals states:**

> It is not uncommon for a programmer to write an equals method that
>   looks like this, and then spend hours puzzling over why it doesn't
>   work properly:
>
> [Code sample here]
>
> The problem is that this method does not override Object.equals, whose
>   argument is of type Object, but overloads it instead.

**Code Sample:**

```
public boolean equals(MyClass o) {
    //...
}
```

**My Question:**

Why is a strongly typed equals method that overloads like the one in this code sample not sufficient?  The book states that overloading rather than overriding is bad, but it doesn't state why this is the case or what scenarios would make this equals method fail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because overloading the method won't change the behavior in places like collections or other places that the `equals(Object)` method is explicitly used. For example, take the following code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public boolean equals(MyClass m) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you put this in something like a `HashSet`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<MyClass> myClasses = new HashSet<>();
    myClasses.add(new MyClass());
    myClasses.add(new MyClass());
    System.out.println(myClasses.size());
}
```

This will print `2`, not `1`, even though you'd expect all `MyClass` instances to be equal from your overload and the set wouldn't add the second instance.

So basically, even though this is `true`:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
new MyClass().equals(myClass);
```

This is `false`:

```
Object o = new MyClass();
new MyClass().equals(o);
```

And the latter is the version that collections and other classes use to determine equality. In fact, the *only* place this will return `true` is where the parameter is explicitly an instance of `MyClass` or one of its subtypes.

---

**Edit:** per your question:

**Overriding versus Overloading**

Let's start with the difference between overriding and overloading. With overriding, you actually *redefine* the method. You remove its original implementation and actually replace it with your own. So when you do:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
```

You're actually re-linking your new `equals` implementation to replace the one from `Object` (or whatever superclass that last defined it).

On the other hand, when you do:

```
public boolean equals(MyClass m) { ... }
```

You're defining an entirely new method because you're defining a method with the same name, but different parameters. When `HashSet` calls `equals`, it calls it on a variable of the type `Object`:

```
Object k;
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
```

(That code is from the source code of `HashMap.put`, which is used as the underlying implementation for `HashSet.add`.)

To be clear, the only time it will use a different `equals` is when an `equals` method is *overridden*, not overloaded. If you try to add `@Override` to your overloaded `equals` method, it will fail with a compiler error, complaining that it doesn't override a method. I can even declare both `equals` methods in the same class, because it's overloading:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(MyClass m) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Generics**

As for generics, `equals` is *not* generic. It explicitly takes `Object` as its type, so that point is moot. Now, let's say you tried to do this:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    public boolean equals(T t) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This won't compile with the message:

> Name clash: The method equals(T) of type MyGenericClass has the same erasure as equals(Object) of type Object but does not override it

And if you try to `@Override` it:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(T t) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll get this instead:

> The method equals(T) of type MyGenericClass must override or implement a supertype method

So you can't win. What's happening here is that Java implements generics using erasure. When Java finishes checking all the generic types on compile time, the actual runtime objects all get replaced with `Object`. Everywhere you see `T`, the actual bytecode contains `Object` instead. This is why reflection doesn't work well with generic classes and why you can't do things like `list instanceof List<String>`.

This also makes it so that you can't overload with generic types. If you have this class:

```
public class Example<T> {
    public void add(Object o) { ... }
    public void add(T t) { ... }
}
```

You'll get compiler errors from the `add(T)` method because when the classes are actually done compiling, the methods would both have the same signature, `public void add(Object)`.

Comment: +1, good example :) why do containers like HashSet prefer Object.Equals over calling the .Equals method of their template-parameter class (MyClass in your example)?

Comment: It's also worth noting that Java doesn't have any kind of dynamic method resolution for overloaded methods. I'm not sure if there are any strongly-typed languages (Java, C#, C++, etc.) that do. The JVM won't check to see if it's passing a `MyClass` and call the overloaded method instead. It just sees that it's supposed to call `equals(Object)` on `Object`, and when it does, it checks for methods that _override_ `equals(Object)`.

Comment: I'd assume that Java's HashSet actually calls Object.hashCode() or its overrides to determine equality of the objects inserted, like C# does.

Comment: @TomLint No. C# and Java *both* use the `hashCode` to determine the bucket of the linked list, but they **DO NOT** use the `hashCode` to determine equality. [Relevant link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc415bcb-68fe-4619-9c25-acd8924f731f/hash-table-buckets?forum=csharpgeneral).

Answer (score 12):

> Why is a strongly typed equals method that overloads like the one in this code sample not sufficient?

Because it doesn't override `Object.equals`. Any general purpose code which only knows about the method declared in `Object` (e.g. `HashMap`, testing for key equality) won't end up calling your overload - they'll just end up calling the original implementation which gives reference equality.

Remember that *overloading* is determined at compile-time, whereas *overriding* is determined at execution time.

If you're overriding `equals`, it's often a good idea to provide a strongly-typed version *as well*, and delegate to that from the method declared in `equals`.

Here's a complete example of how it can go wrong:

```
import java.util.*;

final class BadKey {    
    private final String name;

    public BadKey(String name) {
        // TODO: Non-nullity validation
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(BadKey other) {
        return other != null && other.name.equals(name);
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BadKey key1 = new BadKey("foo");
        BadKey key2 = new BadKey("foo");
        System.out.println(key1.equals(key2)); // true

        Map<BadKey, String> map = new HashMap<BadKey, String>();
        map.put(key1, "bar");
        System.out.println(map.get(key2)); // null
    }
}
```

The fix is simply to add an override, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Delegate to the more strongly-typed implementation
    // where appropriate.
    return other instanceof BadKey && equals((BadKey) other);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) so, why wouldn't the HashMap, for example, invoke the class-specific equality method? Wouldn't the template/generics mechanism in Java let the containers invoke the method on the template parameter type rather than simply calling Object.equals?

Comment: `equals()` is not generic. It takes an Object as argument, not a generic type. And collections can hold any kinds of objects, so they must be able to compare apples with oranges, and not just apples with apples.

Comment: Ah, so if equals() was generic, would it work? Or would type erasure cause it to still invoke the Object.equals() method? Or could you even create a generic equals...?

Comment: @xdhmoore You could have a generic `equals()`, this would work similar to the `compareTo(T o)` method used in ordered collections.  Imagine an `Equicomparable<T>` interface with one method, `public boolean equals(T o)`.  But you'd have to be careful, because using the wrong type of object would result in a call to `Object.equals()`, instead of a type error.

Answer (score 2):

Because the collections using equals will use the `Object.equals(Object)` method (potentially overridden in MyClass, and thus called polymorphically), which is different from the `MyClass.equals(MyClass)`.

Overloading a method defines a **new, different** method, that happens to have the same name as another one.