# Is it ugly design that I overload a method depending on whether the argument is subtype or supertype?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

Is it ugly design that I overload a method depending on whether the argument is subtype or supertype?

I intend to implent a super class A and a subclass B, and the objects can compare with each other.

compareTo is overloaded twice both in class A and class B, and the code seems a little messy.
It feels like ugly design. I'm not sure if there is a more elegant approach.

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    private Integer x;

    public A(Integer i) {
        x = i;
    }

    public Integer getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int compareTo(A other) {
        return x.compareTo(other.getX());
    }

    public int compareTo(B other) {
        return x.compareTo(other.getX() + other.getY());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private Integer y;

    public B(Integer a, Integer b) {
        super(a);
        y = b;
    }

    public Integer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getX() + y, other.getX());
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(B other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getX() + y, other.getX() + other.getY());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a bad design. Something like this would be better.

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {
    private Integer x;

    public A(Integer i) {
        x = i;
    }

    public Integer getX() {
        return getX();
    }

    protected Integer compareValue() {
        return getX();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A other) {
        return compareValue().compareTo(other.compareValue());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    Integer y;

    public B(Integer a, Integer b) {
        super(a);
        y = b;
    }

    public Integer getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compareValue() {
        return getX() + getY();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bad design, yes. Specifically, it violates transitivity. From the [`Comparable` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-):

> The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)` implies `x.compareTo(z)>0`.

When you introduce inheritance, you lose transitivity. That's because your `A.compareTo(B)` method doesn't actually override anything, and so if you passed a `List<A>` to `Collections.sort()` which contained both `A` and `B`, it would end up using the `A.compareTo(A)` method for the `A` instances and the `B.compareTo(A)` method for the `B` instances. As you've written them, they are *not* transitive, and therefore would result in unpredictable ordering since reversing the comparison can change the sort order.

I wrote a similar response w.r.t. `Object.equals` and why you can't overload it a while back, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787947/overriding-object-equals-vs-overloading-it/12788083#12788083).

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. May I know how to re-structure the code to improve? Thank you

Comment: OldCurmudgeon's restructure would work as long as none of the subclasses override your `compareTo` method to do something different. You could enforce that by making the `compareTo` method `final`.