# The Object's equals Method?

Tags: java, equals

Can anybody explain why the first code equates to false and the second to true?
[image]

[image]

Comment: please add a language tag, and type out your code

Comment: Because nobody calls `Circle.equals(Circle circle)`. Don't post pictures of text here. Post the text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

All objects in Java start with the `equals(Object)` method, found in the base `Object` class. Your second example simply overrides this method, so that any time the `equals(Object)` method is called, the override implementation is used rather than the base implementation.

However, in your first example, you have added a *new* overload for the `equals()` method, with a parameter list different from the based `Object.equals()` method. This overload would be used any time you call it when both of these are true:

1. The reference used to call the method has a compile-time type of `Circle`, and
2. The parameter passed to the method has a compile-time type of `Circle`

The first condition is required so that the compiler can find the method in the first place. If the compile-time type of the target instance of the call is not `Circle`, then the `equals(Circle)` overload of the method will not even be considered as a possibility.

The second condition is required so that the compiler can identify the `equals(Circle)` overload as the one to be called. If the parameter being passed is not known at compile time to be `Circle`, then the compiler can't safely use the `equals(Circle)` method, and must instead choose the `equals(Object)` overload.

In your first example, the compile-time types of both the target instance for the method call, as well as the parameter passed to the method, is `Object` and not `Circle`. As such, the compiler has no safe way to call the `equals(Circle)` overload, and must instead call `equals(Object)`. And that overload, the base implementation, simply compares the references of the two objects, returning `true` only if they are identical (which in this case, being two different instances, obviously are not).

See also [Overriding Object.equals VS Overloading it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12787947)

As an aside: the second implementation is not quite right, because it assumes that the `circle` parameter passed in is always of type `Circle`. This is true in the degenerate code example in your question, but would not be *generally* true in a real-world program. A correct implementation of `equals(Object)` would check the type of the parameter first, and immediately return `false` if the type was not correct.